# Sentry 2 permissions array

Tags: php, arrays, cartalyst-sentry

I have an admin panel which enables admins to assign different permissions to a user. The way that I do this is through tick boxes and when ticked it should assign a 1 to that permission.

The only problem is, the permissions are dynamic and so needs to go through a loop. I've had some trouble trying to grasp how I would got about assigning permissions this way as in my guess needs to loop through an array and then place the values into another array.

Does anyone know how I would go about this?

I have tried things like...

```
$park = Input::get('parks');
$permissions = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($park); $i++)
{
    $permissions = $park[$i] => 1;
}
```

Or...

```
$park = Input::get('parks');

for($i = 0; $i < count($park); $i++)
{
    $park[$i] => 1;
}
```

Obviously the first one comes up with errors, but the second one will just come out as [1,1,1,1] .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*the second one will just come out as [1,1,1,1].*" — Obviously. What do you want it to do output instead?

Comment: In Sentry the permissions need to look like this... {1:1,2:1} or {"1":1,"2":1} within the database.

Comment: @CheckeredMichael, did you find the solution? I also want to create a dynamic permission through checkbox from admin panel. If you found the solution, then save me.